# Design Issue with Automated Test (Selenium WebDriver + Spring Boot + Cucumber + Page Object Model + PageFactory Pattern)

Tags: spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pageobjects

I am building an automated test framework using these tools and concepts -

- Selenium WebDriver
- Cucumber (For BDD)
- Spring Boot
- Page Object Model
- PageFactory Pattern

Everything is working fine and I am happy with what I have built. Following Page Object Model, I have created PageObject classes which are basically models of actual web pages. I am also using PageFactory pattern to automatically instantiate WebElements.

I have leveraged Spring Boot, for awesomeness. By awesomeness I mean stuff like auto injecting configurations throughout the application, dependency injection required to achieve sharing of the test world between Step Definition classes while performing Cucumber Tests, and other goals which would have been a bit tedious to achieve without it.

Given the background, let's now come to my question.

I want my Page Objects to be Spring managed beans/components. I am initializing my Page Objects using `PageFactory.initElements(WebDriver driver, Object page)` method from the constructor. As far as my knowledge takes me, if page objects are initialized before the pages are actually loaded in browser, then any attempts to invoke action on their web elements will result in `StaleStateException`. Correct? So, if I make my page objects Spring managed beans, how do I control the initialization of its web elements? I can remove the PageFactory's initialization method from the constructor and put it in some other method which I can later call to instantiate it. But I wany to know if there is any better approach to this.

The program should be able to autowire page objects in Step Definition classes of Cucumber, but elements of those objects should be instantiated whenever the actual page is loaded in the browser or some action method is called to interact with the web element.

**Is it good idea to make PageObjects spring beans, if you are following Page Object Model and PageFactory?**

Comment: I am not using java, but I think that initialization of the page object has nothing to do with the `StaleStateException`, as far as i know you get this exception if you are finding the element(resulting in an object), then the page reloads/changes and you are trying to call an action on that object. You need to make sure the page will not change/reload between finding the element and using it to call an action on it.

Comment: Check this and see if helps https://peterkedemo.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/writing-good-selenium-tests-with-page-objects-and-spring/

Comment: @lauda You are absolutely correct. And, thank you for redirecting me to that blog. It really looks promising. I will experiment with that approach.

Comment: Did you find a reasonable answer to your problem? Did you end up using Peter's approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `PageFactory.initElements()` method only creates proxies of actual web elements rather than caching them. So, no matter when I do the initialization, every time when a method is called on a WebElement, the driver will first find it on the current page and then simulate the action on the WebElement.

The only thing that will cause state state is if the page changes or reloads. Thank you for pointing this out.

But whenever we use `@CacheLookup` annotation, we will be losing one of the page factory benefit as it will find the element once and then keep a reference to it, hence, we are more likely to see StaleElementExceptions.

This blog might help others - http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver